# React justifyContent: "space-between" does not work with columns

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styles

In my code the bottom Box does not get pushed to the bottom of the screen it just shows below the top Box like in second image.( I dont want to use any libraries)

**What i need**
[image: box layout]
**My result**

[image: box layout my result]

```
<View style={{ flex:1 }}>
 <View style={{ justifyContent: "space-between", flexDirection: "row" }}>
     <Box />
     <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
         <Box />
         <Box />
     </View>
     </View>
     <View style={{ justifyContent: "space-between", flexDirection: "column"}}>
         <Box />
     </View>
</View>
```

Also if i try to have simple space-between column it does not work, but when i set direction to "row" it works, but it has to be column.

```
<View style={{ justifyContent: "space-between", flexDirection: "column" }}>
     <Box />
      <Box />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I Achive this.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {  View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


const Box =()=>{
  return(<View style={styles.box}></View>)
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.seconCont}>
      <Box/>
      <Box/>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.thirdCont}>
      <Box/>
      <Box/>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:"row",
    backgroundColor:'red'
   
  },
  seconCont:{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:"column",
    justifyContent:"space-between",
     backgroundColor:'green'
  },
   thirdCont:{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:"row",
    justifyContent:"space-between",
     backgroundColor:'blue'
  },
  box:{
    width:50,
    height:50,
    backgroundColor:"orange",
   
  }
 
});
```

I have also setup an Snack example.
https://snack.expo.dev/4QJYzNJz-

Answer (score -1):

if may handle it very easily with using ant design library for it as it have there built-in API's for each card manipulation by using grids:
Link:
http://roylee0704.github.io/react-flexbox-grid/

Comment: It's not clear that this library will solve the problem the user is having. I think they want CSS help, instead.